# Javascript not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I am building a site for my first freelance client, he is having issues on Internet Explorer (barf) at his end when he tests it, I have tried on a Windows computer and the virtual machine on my Mac and in both cases it has worked.

Here's what's meant to happen:

1. User fills out the form
2. User clicks submit
3. Ajax validates using a php script
4. If validation is ok - send emails with another php script, otherwise show error
5. When validation succeeds and emails send, show a success message.

It all works as expected for me, but for the client the submit button doesn't do anything.

Also, on the FAQ page (2nd link in menu at top), clicking on a question has no effect whereas it should bring up an answer (as it does for me!).

The site is [here](http://adamjwaite.co.uk/sacv3/HTML/)

Why should it work on my version of IE and not his? Is it perhaps he has something blocking the Javascript? I'm at a loss with this, can anyone else reproduce the error or is it just him?

It's worth mentioning that the site functions correctly on all other browsers.

Comment: What version of IE are you and your client using? Is it the same?

Comment: the site is always showing a Gateway Timeout error...
PS: as lorenzo-s stated, what version of IE are you both using?

Comment: IE9 was used, he tried IE8 and had the same issue though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got it. It does not work for me neither, until I open the IE Script Console (F12).

So, the problem is that in your Javascript you used **`console.log('something')`** somewhere. Remeber to **always remove** calls to this method after you finish your debugging stuffs, because `console` is not defined in IE until the console is hidden (and it's always hidden on a non-dev computer). The fact it's undefined, throws an error on `log()` method call that breaks your entire script.

Comment: IE 9 in normal mode works, in compatibily mode I get this: ``var retval = JSON.parse(data);`` in line 253. Thats before the console.log() line

Comment: @timaschew Mee to. For some reason, in compatibility mode `JSON` does not seems to be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try commenting out all of the console logs! God I hate that browser so much! I console log in a conditional comment on load of the page saying something along the lines of 'eurgh, internet explorer' ha. Thanks all for you help, I'll let you know if it's fixed when I get home!

Comment: @AdamWaite If you want to leave debugging, try to make a custom wrapper for console logging, like `function myConsoleLog(message) { try { console.log(message); } catch (x) { } }`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate fix that worked for me is to patch in the `console.log` object with something like:

```
if ( !console ) var console = { log: function() { } };
```

then you can keep your console out messages for debugging purposes.